# How to mute notification sounds during a call on Samsung Galaxy 6 Edge?

Tags: notifications, audio, samsung-galaxy-s-6

While on a call, if I receive a text message, the notification sound for text message plays during the call. How do I mute the notification sounds for text messages while I'm on a phone call? My device is Samsung Galaxy 6 Edge.

Answer (score 1):

This action in the Samsung Galaxy is controlled by the setting 'Alerts on call'.

It is set from within the default Phone app. After you have opened the Dialer, open Call Settings > Call Alerts > Alerts on call.

Deselect this setting to turn it off.